# Determining the size of a file larger than 4GB

Tags: c++, c, fseek, fgetpos

The code currently does this and the fgetpos does handle files larger than 4GB but the seek returns an error, so any idea how to seek to the end of a `file > 4GB`?

```
fpos_t currentpos;

sok=fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END);
assert(sok==0,"Seek error!");

fgetpos(fp,&currentpos);
m_filesize=currentpos;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you sure that fgetpos is working correctly if you haven't gotten to the end of the file?

Comment: fpos_t is not an integer type so the last line is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're in Windows, you want [GetFileSizeEx (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364957(VS.85).aspx). The return value is a 64bit int.

On linux [stat64 (manpage)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/stat64/) is correct. fstat if you're working with a FILE*.

Answer (score 9):

Ignore all the answers with "64" appearing in them. On Linux, you should add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to your CFLAGS and use the `fseeko` and `ftello` functions which take/return `off_t` values instead of `long`. These are not part of C but POSIX. Other (non-Linux) POSIX systems may need different options to ensure that `off_t` is 64-bit; check your documentation.

Comment: Could you provide references?

Comment: @qed: "Not part of POSIX": See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html ; Usage of `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`: see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me in Linux:

```
int64_t bigFileSize(const char *path)
{
    struct stat64 S;

    if(-1 == stat64(path, &S))
    {
        printf("Error!\r\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return S.st_size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

(stolen from the glibc manual)

`int fgetpos64 (FILE *stream, fpos64_t *position)`

This function is similar to fgetpos but the file position is returned in a variable of type `fpos64_t` to which position points.

If the sources are compiled with `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS == 64` on a 32 bits machine this function is available under the name `fgetpos` and so transparently replaces the old interface.

Answer (score 2):

Stat is always better than fseek to determine file size, it will fail safely on things that aren't a file.
64 bit filesizes is an operating specific thing, on gcc you can put "64" on the end of the commands, or you can force it to make all the standard calls 64 by default. See your compiler manual for details.

Answer (score 1):

On linux, at least, you could use lseek64 instead of fseek.